# TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' when creating a new definition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, typeerror, function-definition

I'm creating a definition to calculate mean,sem and count for parameter 1, parameter 2 and the value. Each .mean(), .sem(), .count(), .groupby() all come from pandas library.

```
def mean_SEM_Count(para1,para2,value):
    mean=df.groupby([para1],[para2])[value].mean()
    SEM=df.groupby([para1],[para2])[value].sem()
    COUNT=df.groupby([para1],[para2])[value].count()
```

So when I use this definition, I can call the values for each (para1, para2, value) from my dataframe (df) which comes from an Excel sheet

Example:

```
df1 = mean_SEM_Count(para1 = 'Time', para2 = 'drug', value = 'food')
```

But I get the following error:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Change `df.groupby([para1],[para2])` to `df.groupby([para1,para2])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is necessary change:

```
df.groupby([para1],[para2])
```

to:

```
df.groupby([para1,para2])
```

Btw, here is possible use only [`GroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.agg.html):

```
out = df.groupby([para1,para2])[para3].agg(['mean','sem','count'])
```